# assertTitle fails on Selenium + PHPUnit

Tags: selenium, yii, phpunit, pcre

I am trying a very simple test like this :

```
public function index()
{
    $this->open('');
    $this->assertTitle(Yii::app()->name);
}
```

with the appropriate fixtures :

```
'accueil' => array(
    'id' => 1,
    'title' => Yii::app()->name,
    'name' => "accueil",
    [etc...]
),
```

But when I run the functional test, the **assertTitle** method fails :

> Failed command: assertTitle('comptabilite-personnelle.net (dev)')
>   Failed asserting that 'comptabilite-personnelle.net (dev)' matches
>   PCRE pattern "/^comptabilite-personnelle.net (dev)$/".

OTOH, the following code does not fail :

Fixtures :

```
'accueil' => array(
    'id' => 1,
    'title' => 'whatever',
    'name' => "accueil",
    [etc...]
),
```

Assertion :

```
    $this->assertTitle('whatever');
```

Any idea about this behavior welcome !

Comment: What is the value of `Yii::app()->name` in those cases? `assertTitle` takes [string-match pattern](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/0.8.0/reference.html#patterns) as parameter. By default it is treated as glob. Try prepending `exact:`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check if your page title contains you app name and not want to check if your page title is exactly the same as your app name you need to do it like that:

```
$this->assertTitle('regexp:.*' . Yii::app()->name . '.*');
```